# Can you reference the environment in $HOME/.gitconfig

Tags: git

I've got an NFS mounted home directory on most of the machines I work on with a .gitconfig that specifies a hard-coded path to `$HOME/.gitignore` for `core.excludesfile`.
I've recently started working on another box that doesn't mount that home directory, and the path to my home directory there is different.  I would like to keep the files consistent (I don't want to edit the `.gitconfig` every time I copy my dotfiles to a new box), so I'd like to put this in `.gitconfig`:

```
excludesfile = $HOME/.gitignore
```

Sadly, git does not expand `$HOME`.  Is there anyway to get that functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like excludesfile understands `~` for referencing the home directory.